# Subtract date from current date and return only Years

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to subtract a date(stored in db) from current date and return only the year part from it.
Currently for test purposes i am doing some thing like this but the return result is wrong

```
print DATEDIFF (year ,1993-04-24,getdate())
```

The return value is 107.
The system date is perfectly right.

Is there something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `'` around your date

```
select DATEDIFF (year , '1993-04-24', GETDATE())
```

Comment: Oh. Thank You very much. Eagle's eye